# How to implement a bg-images slider with tailwind css?

Tags: tailwind-css

Can someone advise or provide an example on how to implement a background image slider with tailwind css?
To set a single image i have to do as follow:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'my_bg_image' : "url('../public/bg.png')",
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

then return a div as follow:

```
return (
  <div
    className="bg-scroll bg-[url('/bg.png')] h-[972px]"
  >
  </div>
)
```

What if i want this image change, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Mainly you will need Carousel wrapper, Slider indicators , Slider controls.

Refer to this :
https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/

OR you can use this:

html file:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="relative">
            <ul id="slider">
                <li class="h-[50vh] relative">
                    <img class="h-full w-full object-cover" src="./img1.jpg" alt="">
                </li>
                <li class="h-[50vh] relative hidden">
                    <img class="h-full w-full object-cover" src="./img2.jpg" alt="">
                </li>
                <li class="h-[50vh] relative hidden">
                    <img class="h-full w-full object-cover" src="./img3.jpg" alt="">
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="absolute px-5 flex h-full w-full top-0 left-0">
                <div class="my-auto w-full flex justify-between">
                    <button onclick="prev()" class="bg-white p-3 bg-opacity-70 shadow-lg rounded-full">Button 1</button>
                    <button onclick="next()" class="bg-white p-3 bg-opacity-70 shadow-lg rounded-full">Button 2</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```

js file:

```
curr_slide = 1;

sliderElemnt = document.getElementById('slider');
total_slides = sliderElemnt.childElementCount;
// console.log(total_slides);

function next() {
  if (curr_slide < total_slides) {
    curr_slide++;
    slide_show();
  }
}

function prev() {
  if (curr_slide > 1) {
    curr_slide--;
    slide_show();
  }
}

function slide_show() {
  slides = document.getElementById('slider').getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (let index = 0; index < total_slides; index++) {
    const element = slides[index];
    if(curr_slide == index+1){
      element.classList.remove('hidden');
    }else{
        element.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this @riyaroy2086 , i have added more details to understand what i want to achieve here, can the carrousel be set as bg itself?

Comment: @Leo , I have edited the code, you can check out and also inserting the backgroundImage in the theme section of tailwind would be a bit complex to implement.
Try to use it this way.

Comment: thanks for your help, it is not really what i wanted but this could do the trick